# Trying to find non-duplicate entries in mostly identical tables(access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 different databases. They track different things about inventory. in essence they share 3 common fields. Location, item number and quantity. I've extracted these into 2 tables, with only those fields. Every time I find an answer, it doesn't get all the test cases, just some of the fields. 
Items can be in multiple locations, and as a turn each location can have multiple items. The primary key would be location and item number.

I need to flag when an entry doesn't match all three fields.

I've only been able to find queries that match an ID or so, or who's queries are beyond my comprehension. in the below, I'd need a query that would show that rows 1,2, and 5 had issues. I'd run it on each table and have to verify it with a physical inventory.

Please refrain from commenting on it being silly having information in 2 different databases, All I get in response it to deal with it =P

```
Table A
Location  ItemNum   | QTY
-------------------------
1a1a     |  as1001  |  5
1a1b     |  as1003  |  10
1a1b     |  as1004  |  2
1a1c     |  as1005  |  15
1a1d     |  as1005  |  15

Table B
Location  ItemNum   | QTY
-------------------------
1a1a     |  as1001  |  10
1a1d     |  as1003  |  10
1a1b     |  as1004  |  2
1a1c     |  as1005  |  15
1a1e     |  as1005  |  15
```

[This article seemed to do what I wanted but I couldn't get it to work.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compare-two-tables-and-find-records-without-matches-CB20AD48-4EBA-402A-B20D-EAF10A5D1CB4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find entries in Table A that don't have an exactly matching entry in Table B:

```
select A.* 
from A 
left join B on A.location = B.location and A.ItemNum = B.ItemNum and A.qty = B.qty 
where B.location Is Null
```

Just swap all the A's and B's to get the list of entries in B with no matching entry in A.